# Python command line for clicking this button with chrome driver

Tags: python-3.x, macos, google-chrome, webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I am just starting learning python and i am testing a script that automatically performs some steps on chrome driver. I am currently finding it difficult to program the following. When my script opens a link in chrome driver it should click a specific button. However sometimes before the script gets to this page, another screen comes first with a question for a subscription. I need my script to click no on the subscription offer, but only IF it pops up. How would i be able to input this into my script? So sometimes the link immediately goes to the right page but sometimes i get to the subscription page.

looking forward to receive some tips!

regards,
Julian

Answer (score 0):

So what I normally do in these cases is I create a function called `close_popup()`, and inside this function, I have the code to close the popup, and in the main code, I add a `try and except` method to capture an exception and run the `close_popup()` function, if it's successful try the failed code again.

A simple code demonstration to help you out:

```
def close_popup():
    try:
        <CLOSE POPUP>
        return True
    except:
        return False

def main():
    try:
        <YOUR CODE>
    except:
        if close_popup():
            <YOUR CODE IF POPUP CLOSED>
        else:
            <YOUR CODE TO RUN IF NOT SUCCESSFULL>
```

Also, I wouldn't recommend using an empty except.
This is not the most optimized work and there are probably better ways to do this but I guess with this you can understand the logic and come with something better.